# In a group text, how do you reply to the same numbers that were originally messaged?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, contacts

I am on the receiving end of this problem and am trying to resolve the issue for my brother, who has an iPhone.

I have two mobile numbers (we'll call them Phone A and Phone B). When my sister (who is on an Android) sends a group text to my brother and to me on **Phone A**, I receive it on Phone A as expected and can reply without issue. However, when my brother replies to the thread, it goes to my sister and to me on **Phone B**. How does my brother resolve this issue so that when he replies to the group thread, it goes to Phone A as intended?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your brother has a different contact for you than your sister does. If your brother replies to you it may be using the number in contacts for you. He would need to change the Contact number to the number you use for Phone A.

Comment: He has a single contact record for me with two phone number entries - one for Phone A and one for Phone B. He would want to maintain that single contact record without having to delete one of the two phone entries within it.

Answer (score 0):

Your brother could "maintain the single contact record" (i.e., one contact card for you) by moving the Phone B number on that card from being one of the named numbers at the top of the card, to instead appearing in the "Notes" section below. Number B would still be on the card, but his iPhone shouldn't then use Number B for a text "reply all."

For example, I dummied up a contact card for you, as it probably now appears in your brother's phone. It includes both your cell number A and cell number B:

[image]

Here's the same contact card, with the cell B number moved down into the "Notes" field:

[image]

If your contact card on your brother's phone is like the second image, when a text is sent to him and to you, and he selects "reply all," his text response to you will be sent to phone A, and not to phone B.

This was done in macOS. Do you need me to do the same in iOS so you can see how it looks there?

Comment: So iOS does not support properly replying to group messages when one or more of the replying user's contacts has a different number set as the default?

Comment: @jwildman16 That's what it looks like to me. Have your brother re-format your contact card on his iPhone, and let us know the result.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "re-format"?

Comment: @jwildman16 I've edited the answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for the mock-up. Makes sense and it should work. I'll let my brother know. However, it's really not a great solution since he wouldn't be able to initiate a new call or message to Phone B when it's in the notes field. At least not directly from the dialer or messages app. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: On my iPhone SE (1st gen, iOS 13.5.1): touch the number in the Notes field, and the iPhone displays a "Copy" flag. Press the "Copy" flag. A contextual menu appears, with "call" as one of the choices. Press "Call." Voilà.